# Averaging multivariate density over a hypercube

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Using a variant of the  notation in Wikipedia's article about Multivariate normal distribution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

, let  $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be an $n$-dimensional vector and $A$  a positive definite (not necessarily symmetric) $n\times n$ matrix, then let the density function

$$f(x)=
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}{x}^T{\boldsymbol A}{x}
\right)$$

Consider  averaging. Suppose that the elements $a_{i,j}$ of $\boldsymbol A$ are small and we are only interested in an averaging  result up to Order $\cal O (a^2)$.

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are  independent $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables, then the average can be performed. Let $\boldsymbol I$ be the unit matrix. Since $\boldsymbol A$ is not necessarily symmetric, we need to consider the symmetric part $\frac12 (\boldsymbol A + \boldsymbol A^T)$ for the integration (see [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/13aa/494c312d57a92d72e408bc4f3503edaac8eb.pdf)). We get

$$<f> = \int \cdots \int f(x) \mathcal{N}(x_1) \cdots \mathcal{N}(x_n) {\rm d} x_1 \cdots {\rm d} x_n\\
=\int \cdots \int  \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}{x}^T{(\boldsymbol I + \boldsymbol A)}{x}
\right) {\rm d} x_1 \cdots {\rm d} x_n\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det (\boldsymbol I + \frac12 (\boldsymbol A + \boldsymbol A^T))}}$$

Now if this is to be evaluated  to Order $\cal O (a^2)$, then we can expand. For simplicity, let $a_{i,i} = 0$. Then we have
$$<f> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det  (\boldsymbol I + \frac12 (\boldsymbol A + \boldsymbol A^T))}} \\
\simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac 14 \sum_{i>j} (a_{i,j} + a_{j,i})^2}} \simeq \exp{\frac18 \sum_{i>j} (a_{i,j} + a_{j,i})^2}$$
where the sum  $\sum_{i>j}$ arises as the sum over all $\binom{n}{2}$ many pairs $i\ne j$  in the Leibniz formula for the determinant's expansion if $n-2$ product factors are kept on  the main diagonal, i.e. have value $1$.

Now the **question** :

Under the same conditions, what is the average of $f(x)$ over the hypercube, i.e. for $X_1,\ldots,X_n$  being independent  binary random variables with $X_i \in \{-1,1\}$ ?

Is there an equivalent (discrete?) procedure to the integration performed above?

A conjecture would be that the approximate result is actually the same as for normally distributed variables, since the elements $a_{i,j}$ are small and we are only interested in an averaging  result up to Order $\cal O (a^2)$.

Comment: Cuadratic forms are usually defined with symmetric matrices, because you don't loose generality. Hence the bit about $A$ not being symmetric and working with the symmetric part is redundant and distracting.

Comment: The Bernoulli variables are not only independent but zero mean, right?

Comment: @leonbloy As said in the beginning of the description, A is a positive definite (not necessarily symmetric) n×n matrix, so the bit about symmetry is necessary.

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, the Bernoulli variables are  independent and zero mean.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything stopping us from peforming a series expansion and perform expectations with quadratic forms? Assume $\mathbf{A}$ is positive definite and symmetric; otherwise, $\mathbf{A} \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^T)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\intercal \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\right) &\simeq 1 + \mathbb{E}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\intercal \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\right] + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^\intercal \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\right)^2\right] \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\mathbf{A}\Sigma) + \frac{1}{8}\left(2\text{tr}(\mathbf{A}\Sigma\mathbf{A}\Sigma)+\left(\text{tr}(\mathbf{A}\Sigma)\right)^2\right) \\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\mathbf{A}) + \frac{1}{8}\left(2\text{tr}(\mathbf{A}^2)+\left(\text{tr}(\mathbf{A})\right)^2\right) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Neat. It should be noted that this is also valid for the original setup, with iid normal variables. We only use $E[X]=0$ and $\Sigma = I$

Comment: Yes, the expansion up front is of course possible. If you compare to the Gaussian case laid out in the description, the question is rather to solve the problem with no expansion - or at least to some accurracy - first,  and then expand. This is why the first part of the question read "Is there an equivalent (discrete?) procedure to the integration performed above?" - in the Gaussian case this led to the determinant solution.

Comment: @Andreas I think this procedure is preferable.

Comment: As explained above, expansion first  gives the result, but processing first without expansion  - or at least to some accurracy - shines more light on the problem, as demonstrated in the Gaussian case. Expansion can always be done later.